# Google Docs form attachments

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

I have created a Google Docs form where respondents can upload attachments. I gave edit privileges to other colleagues but every time they go and check form responses they need my approval to open the attachments.

Do you know why, and how to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. just needed to give access to the attachments folder.